# Integral substitution?

Tags: integration, substitution

In a recent economics paper [(Rhodes and Wilson 2016)](https://sites.google.com/site/andrewrhodeseconomics/files/CPA_July2016.pdf?attredirects=0&d=1), expected buyer surplus is computed as follows (page 8, (4)):

$$ v^*(q) = \int_{p^*(q)}^{b+q}[1-G(z-q)] dz$$

where $G(\cdot)$ is a distribution function.

I think that this basically computes:

$$ E(\varepsilon + q-p | \varepsilon > p-q) = \frac{\int_{p}^{b+q}(\varepsilon-p) g(\varepsilon) d\varepsilon }{1-G(p-q)}$$

How do you substitute for $\varepsilon$ with $z$ in order to get from my expression to their expression?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The integral is the expected consumer surplus in equilibrium (those who do not buy get zero surplus):

$$\int^{p-q}_a0g(\varepsilon)d\varepsilon+\int_{p-q}^b(\varepsilon+q-p)g(\varepsilon)d\varepsilon=\int_{p-q}^b(\varepsilon+q-p)g(\varepsilon)d\varepsilon$$

Substituting $z-q=\varepsilon$ gives

$$\int_{p}^{b+q}(z-p)g(z-q)dz.$$

Integrating by parts, this is:

$$[(z-p)G(z-q)]_p^{b+q}-\int_p^{b+q}G(z-q)dz=(b+q-p)-\int_p^{b+q}G(z-q)dz$$

which is the expression they gave once you substitute $\int_{p}^{b+q}1\,dz=b+q-p$.

---

Note that your own integral is something different. Let $A$ be the event that consumer surplus is nonnegative: $$A=\{\varepsilon\in [a,b]\ | \ \varepsilon+q-p\geq 0\}.$$

The expected consumer surplus in equilibrium is:

$$E([\varepsilon+q-p]\mathbb{1}_A)$$

because those who do not buy get zero surplus.

You calculated something different: consumer's expected surplus conditional on it being nonnegative:

$$E(\varepsilon+q-p \ | \ A)$$

For example if consumer surplus is $-1$ with probability $1/2$ and $1$ with probability $1/2$, then the expected consumer surplus in equilibrium is:

$$\frac{1}{2}0+\frac{1}{2}1=\frac{1}{2}$$

while the consumer surplus conditional on it being positive is $1$.

Comment: Thanks, I can see now how the substitution works. However, you still need to start with dividing by the conditional density, i.e., $1-G(p-q)$, no?

Comment: See my edit. We don't want expected consumer surplus conditional on consumer surplus being positive. We want the expected consumer surplus (which is zero for those that don't buy, and positive for those that do).

Comment: Makes sense ... thanks!